# Getting NullReferenceException When Timer Exceeds Limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the time exceeds the max, it spams me with NullReferenceException errors. I can't seem to figure out why it would give me this error. The errors happen on the same lines of code, both of which being the nested `if` statements. It's probably the `scene.score` but `score` is defined within the `PlayerScript` script.

```
public int timeLimit = 15;
public float startTime = 0;

PlayerScript scene = GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
    if (startTime >= timeLimit)
    {
        if (scene.score >= 25)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("WinScene");
        }
        if (scene.score < 25)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoseScene");
        }
    }
```

*EDIT*
when I test it in Unity, after the time exceeds 15 seconds, it gives me errors telling me that it is on a certain line of code. That being the first nested if statement. I commented out that first one and left the second one to test, and sure enough it told me that this new line was causing the error.

**EDIT**
Looks like switching `GetComponent` with `FindObjectOfType` did the trick. `<PlayerScript>` is a different script that I was trying to pull info from, ie. `score`.

Comment: It sounds like `GetComponent<PlayerScript>()` is returning null. Are you sure `PlayerScript` is a component of this script's GameObject?

Comment: Are you sure your `SceneManager` is not null? One way is to add breakpoints inside both your if loops (which by the way could be If..Else for clarity) and check what is causing the Exception.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL In this case, it's unlikely `SceneManager` is null - it's one of the classes available in the Unity libraries. (It's a static method being called anyways, so it doesn't need an instance.)

Comment: Since I am picky and like reducing lines, if you resolve the NullReferenceException you could simple use this line: `if (startTime >= timeLimit) { SceneManager.LoadScene((scene.score < 25) ? "LoseScene" : "WinScene") }` since the score is either below 25, or 25 & above, there is no other case.

Comment: @Serlite Then you're right, it is most probably the `GetComponent<PlayerScript>()` which returns null.